# Encode image file to base64

Tags: python-3.6, odoo, xml-rpc

I have a trouble to convert an image to base64 and send it through  xml-rpc client, the xml-RPC server respond and gives this error

> a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

```
import base64
        with open(full_path, 'rb') as imgFile:
            image = base64.b64encode(imgFile)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have given file pointer but should give binary data.

You should write as following :

```
import base64
with open(full_path, 'rb') as imgFile:
    image = base64.b64encode(imgFile.read())
```